# Blank page when run php file

Tags: php

When I run the bellow php code & fill all data and submit it I get blank page,
so where the problem here ?

```
<br><br>

Create New User :

<br><br>

<table width="90%" border=0><tr><td>

<FORM ACTION="user_login.php" METHOD=POST>
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=p_action VALUE="Create_New_User">
Username : <br><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=p_in_username SIZE="25"> <BR>
eMail : <br><input type=text name=p_in_email size="25"> <br>

<br> 

<input type=submit value="Submit">

</FORM>



<?php


?>
```

Comment: Does `user_login.php` exist?

Comment: If `user_login.php` responds with a blank page, the problem is almost certainly with `user_login.php`. Posting *that* code would be significantly more helpful—without it, we'd just be taking wild guesses.

Comment: I'm guessing you simply forgot to post the PHP code. Please have a look at your logs and see if there are any errors present. I suggest you enable `display_errors` on your development machine also.

Comment: what for a file is `user_login.php`. The actual or another one?

Comment: Available in this link http://www.bwor.net/news/user_login_php.txt

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form, you will be redirected to the page defined in the 'action' value of your form. In this case: "user_login.php". I assume, you are then not redirecting from there.

Try adding a:

```
header("location: index.php");
```

And replace index.php with where you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

please check your PHP configuration, is errors and warnings are ON ? it will be better if you share you php code.